# CSS flexbox height auto/100% and height/min-height

Tags: css, flexbox

Look at the code below, also available in [codepen](https://codepen.io/isaac_e/pen/abXgypR)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid#333;
  min-height: 200px;
  /* height: 200px; */
}

.flex-container > * {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.red   { background-color: red;   }
.green { background-color: green; }
.blue  { background-color: blue;  }

.green {
  /* height: 100%; */
  /* height: auto; */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="red">R</div>
  <div class="green">G</div>
  <div class="blue">B</div>
</div>
```

The issue arises when attempting to vertically stretch the green element. I've tried using both `height: auto;` and `height: 100%;` within the `.green` selector. Interestingly, `height: auto;` works as expected, while `height: 100%;` doesn’t produce the same effect, despite flex items stretching in the cross axis by default.

Furthermore, when changing `min-height` to `height` in `.flex-container`, unexpectedly, `height: 100%;` starts working correctly.

Could anyone explain this behavior?

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Comment: A height in percentages, needs the parent element to have an explicit height as well. With `height: 100%` on the container, you are giving it that - with just `min-height: 100%`, you are not.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to do something like this then this code will help you:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
   html,body{height: 100%;}

.flex-container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-container > * {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.red   { background-color: red;   }
.green { background-color: green;}
.blue  { background-color: blue;  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="red">R</div>
    <div class="green">G</div>
    <div class="blue">B</div>
  </div>
```